# "Error: The injectable 'SocialAuthService' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available." in Angular 12

Tags: angular

I am working on a bigger project and trying to implement Google OAuth Social Login. As soon as I import `SocialLoginModule` and add `import {GoogleLoginProvider, SocialAuthServiceConfig, SocialLoginModule} from "angularx-social-login";` the web page goes blank with the following error:

```
core.js:4036 JIT compilation failed for injectable class SocialAuthService {
    /**
     * @param config A `SocialAuthServiceConfig` object or a `Promise` that resolves to a `SocialAuthServiceConfig` object
     */
    constructor(config) {
        this.p…
getCompilerFacade @ core.js:4036
core.js:4055 Uncaught Error: The injectable 'SocialAuthService' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

The injectable is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.

Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
    at getCompilerFacade (core.js:4055)
    at Module.ɵɵngDeclareFactory (core.js:33083)
    at Module../node_modules/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/angularx-social-login.js (angularx-social-login.js:327)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.1
Node: 14.17.3
Package Manager: npm 7.19.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.1
@angular/cdk                    12.1.4
@angular/flex-layout            10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material               12.1.4
@schematics/angular             12.2.1
rxjs                            7.3.0
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I've done:

`npm i angularx-social-login`, then I added `SocialLoginModule` to imports in `app.module.ts` and imported it with `import {SocialLoginModule} from "angularx-social-login";`, and this is the point when I get the error.

Comment: Try and run ngcc or npm i. It looks like that package wasn’t processed.

Comment: @MikeOne I already deleted `node_modules` package and run `npm i` but didn't help.

Comment: What version of angularx-social-login are you using?

Comment: I just run `npm i angularx-social-login`. This should be compatible with angular 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by:

1. Deleting `node_modules` and `.angular` folders
2. Running `npm install`
3. Running `ng serve` again

Answer (score 0):

```
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig, GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';



const config = new AuthServiceConfig ([
     {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('your-id')}
    ]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .....
  ],
  imports: [
     SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig
    }
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but I have problem with the import. When I import SocialLoginModule I get an error according to the title of this question.